# How to implement Benford's law in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, benfords-law

I want to implement a version of Benford's law (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)
that basically asks for the first digit of a number to do analysis on the distribution.

```
1934---> 1
0.04 ---> 4
-56 ---> 5
```

How do you do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways you can do this...

- Using [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html):

  ```
  wholeNumber = 1934;                      %# Your number
  numberString = num2str(wholeNumber,16);  %# Convert to a string
  matches = regexp(numberString,'[1-9]','match');  %# Find matches
  firstNumber = str2double(matches{1});  %# Convert the first match to a double
  ```
- Using [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html):

  ```
  wholeNumber = 0.04;                      %# Your number
  numberString = num2str(wholeNumber,16);  %# Convert to a string
  isInSet = ismember(numberString,'123456789');  %# Find numbers that are
                                                 %#  between 1 and 9
  numberIndex = find(isInSet,1);           %# Get the first number index
  firstNumber = str2double(numberString(numberIndex));  %# Convert to a double
  ```

**EDIT:**

Some discussion of this topic has arisen on one of [the MathWorks blogs](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/04/08/puzzler-benfords-law/). Some interesting additional solutions are provided there. One issue that was brought up was having vectorized solutions, so here's one vectorized version I came up with:

```
numberVector = [1934 0.04 -56];
numberStrings = cellstr(num2str(numberVector(:),16));
firstIndices = regexp(numberStrings,'[1-9]','once');
firstNumbers = cellfun(@(s,i) s(i),numberStrings,firstIndices);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function res = first_digit(number)
    number = abs(number);
    res = floor(number / (10 ^ floor(log10(number))));
end
```

It works for all real numbers (see gnovice's comment for an extreme case)

Comment: Whoops, promise I didn't copy your answer, Yassin! You must have posted while I was figuring out my solution. +1 for thinking of using abs() to cover those pesky negatives.

Comment: +1: I knew there was probably some way to do it mathematically, but the first solutions I thought of were string-based.

Comment: Actually, I just found an extreme case where this solution fails but the string solution works. Try `number = eps(realmin)`. Admittedly, it's not a *likely* scenario you'll run into. I was just seeing how the solutions performed on extreme values.

Answer (score 1):

Using log10 and floor built in functions,

```
floor(x./10.^floor(log10(x)))
```

returns the first digit of all elements in an array as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add another string-based solution (vectorized as well):

```
FirstDigit = @(n) sscanf(num2str(abs(n(:)),'%e'), '%1d', numel(n));
```

and tested on the cases mentioned here:

```
>> FirstDigit( [1934 0.04 -56 eps(realmin)] )
ans =
     1
     4
     5
     4
```